# Recursive and random grouping a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, recursion

I'm trying to write a function which creates dichotomously grouped list, f. ex. if my input is as following:

> [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

I want to choose random integer which will split it into smaller sublists again and again recursively until the sublists' length is maximum two, like:

> [[a, [b, c]], [d, [[e, f], [g, h]]]]

This is what I've got so far but still gives me 
TypeError(list indices must be integers or slices, not list):

```
def split_list(l):
    if l.__len__() > 2:
        pivot = np.random.random_integers(0, l.__len__() - 1)
        print(pivot, l)
        l = [RandomTree.split_list(l[:pivot])][RandomTree.split_list(l[pivot:])]
    return l
```

I got stuck and I would be very thankful for any advice.

Comment: what's `RandomTree`?

Comment: It is not entirely clear how the length of each total grouping in the list is decided. For instance, should the list always start with a grouping of the first three items? What if the length of the list is ten, instead of eight?

Comment: @Uriel RandomTree is just my class where split_list is defined.

Comment: @Ajax1234 no, this grouping was just an example. I want to choose random index of grouping for each iteration (as long as the sublist is bigger than 2).

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer a bit given the information about being-part-of class. let me know if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will not make one-element lists, as per your example:

```
import random

def splitlist(l, minlen=2):
    if len(l) <= minlen:  # if the list is 2 or smaller,
        return l if len(l) > 1 else l[0]  # return the list, or its only element
    x = random.randint(1, len(l)-1)  # choose a random split
    return [splitlist(l[:x], minlen), splitlist(l[x:], minlen)]
```

Usage example:

```
>>> splitlist(list(range(8)))
[[0, [1, [2, [3, 4]]]], [[5, 6], 7]]
```

Comment: your solution is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: your answer is different from mine only in using a list creation instead of concatenation (which adds the requirement for a redundant fix for one element lists). while I don't mind you posting it, I fail to see how did it add something beyond the previously given answer, and why was it necessary. just curious.

Comment: Looking at your answer (having not tested it), it seemed like the one element case was not covered by it. I also find the list creation more readable than your concatenation version. I guess I could have posted my suggestions as a comment under your answer.

Comment: It does cover the one element case, by it's nature. Look again on the recursion - the one element recursion-halt case returns a list which is concatenated to another (and both are at least one element long) so there is no possibility for less than 2 elements sublist. That's what I meant by noting the fix you had to perform to cover for that.

Answer (score 6):

Your question isn't very clear about the datatypes used and seems to use a kinda non-traditional type of recursion (probably as a part of a class). For the error scroll down a bit.

I took the liberty to alter the code a bit and use the normal `random` library, so what you are looking for could look like

```py
import random # at the module-declaration part of your program

def split_list (l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return l
    pivot = random.randint(1, len(l) - 1)
    return [RandomTree.split_list(l[:pivot]) + RandomTree.split_list(l[pivot:])]
```

We are halting the recursion on a single element list, and applying the recursion further if we hadn't stopped yet, using a random index pulled of the possible range (note that `random.randint` generates an index with the specified boundaries *included*).

---

Your error is not using any concatention operator between the two parts of the return value.

`[A][B]` does not concatenate both lists, but rather tries to index the list given in `B` (in your case) from `A`, which is a type-ly wrong usage.

Therefore you can resort to the original function (with the deprecated `numpy` random) as

```
def split_list(l):
    if l.__len__() > 2:
        pivot = np.random.random_integers(0, l.__len__() - 1)
        l = [RandomTree.split_list(l[:pivot])] + [RandomTree.split_list(l[pivot:])]
    return l
```